# jQuery next() - selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a few sets of javascript codes and divs just below them:

```
     <script type='text/javascript'>
                    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                        jQuery(".display").something({
                        /*myfunction*/
                        });
                    });
                </script>

        <div class="display"></div>  

     <script type='text/javascript'>
                    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                        jQuery(".display").something({
                        /*myfunction*/
                        });
                    });
                </script>

        <div class="display"></div>      

(...)
```

Is there a way of selecting only the .display div after exact JS? I've been thinking about next() but it's hard to attach to document.ready ;)

Comment: FYI, "code" in this context is a non-countable noun. Thus "codes" is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything was generated dynamically (that's why I asked how to change my JS code, WITHOUT touching DOM!).

Anyways I've found the best way.

```
<?php $id = rand(); ?>

 <script type='text/javascript'>
                    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                        jQuery(".display-"<?php echo $id;?>").something({
                        /*myfunction*/
                        });
                    });
                </script>

        <div class="display-<?php echo $id;?>"></div>
```

Not perfect, but it works at least (and could possibly break, but chances are really low).

Comment: Can't you keep a count of the number of sections you've generated and use that? And I'd suggest using an id rather than a class, as it's a unique value.

Comment: As stated by several of us, generating HTML dynamically in no way means that you cannot touch the DOM. Indeed, you are already doing so by the very definition of your code generation. And, in fact, your solution is pretty much what the rest of us were advising you to do. I'm sorry that we were not clear enough for you to understand us.

Answer (score 3):

You should give each `<div>` an `id` and attach handlers that way.

Javascript doesn't really care where within HTML you write it. Put all your Javascript in a script file and refer to DOM elements by className/id.

Comment: I can't, every div and script is generated dynamically.

Comment: @anonymous: Of course you can. Generate an ID or Class for the `<div>`s when you generate them, and have one script to handle them.

Answer (score 1):

Just give each DIV a unique id, and use that id in your selector.

Comment: I can't, every div and script is generated dynamically.

Comment: So why can't that dynamic generation use a different id for each section of Javascript+HTML?

Answer (score 0):

You could give the script tag a unique id and call next():

```
<script id="script-tag-1">
jQuery(function() {
  var node = $('#script-tag-1').next('.display');
});
</script>
<div><!-- content --></div>
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SYgEX/

Comment: You should put the IDs on the `<div>` tags not the `<script>` tags.

Comment: Why `should`? Maybe he wants to add javascript logic without messing with existing html or has a very modular system where the script "adds" features but is not necessary to run.

Comment: Because putting ids on script objects is completely weird and nobody ever does it. It's completely breaking the separation of form and function.

Comment: That's what functions are for.